# How to deploy/run Sinatra app on Mac via Passenger?

Tags: macos, deployment, sinatra, passenger, gitosis

We have a git server running on Gitosis hosting our projects. We have created an interface to display info about our repos, and now need to deploy it to the Mac running gitosis. The files for the Sinatra app need to reside in the /Users/git/repositories folder, but we would also like the Sinatra app to start running whenever the master branch is updated.

Is there a tool specifically for deploying on a Mac/example of a Git hook that will deploy in this manner?

We are looking for the simplest deploy possible. I'm assuming it will run on apache and we'll need to add a virtual host....

EDIT: Passenger Pane looks interesting...anyone use it for this? Also, I suppose the files could reside in our existing Library/WebServer/Documents location and just reference the gitosis repos, given no permissions issues

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your issue correctly, then

1. to deploy try include the following to apache config:

   ```
   Alias /gitosis "/Users/git/repositories/public"
   #YOU HAVE TO ln -s /Users/git/repositories/public /Library/WebServer/Documents/gitosis
   <Directory /Users/git/repositories/public>
     RackBaseURI /gitosis
   </Directory>
   ```
2. to restart just:

   ```
   touch /Users/git/repositories/tmp/restart.txt
   ```